# Getting data from other websites

Tags: database, web

I am creating a website which is used to search books and other details about it for which I have to create a database. to create such huge databases would be hectic so how do people manage getting data for websites these.Is there a easy way?

the website will be like searching a book and it displays the details regarding that and where to purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Some websites, like Amazon allow access to their database through webservices(ie over SOAP protocol etc..). Typically service is limited or you must pay for access to such services.

Other sites do not provide such things. The only way to get data is to screen scrape other webpages for the data(eg just request the html pages and scrape the necessary info). This is tedious and if the page template changes, you have to change your parser...not to mention illegal in many cases...

The only other way would be to manually enter it or have your users enter it.

Comment: Is there any way to create a polling system for books where users would vote for the books they read?